# How to access randomized sequence_item from another sequence?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a testbench where I have two sequences: sequenceA and sequenceB with their corresponding sequence items (sqitemA and sqitemB). sequenceA is input to my DUT and randomly generates the values for sqitemA.

Now, I need to access some of these generated random fields in sqItemA to create a related sqItemB for my sequenceB.

Does UVM provide a mechanism to do this?

For example:

```
class sequenceA extends uvm_sequence;
  rand logic[31:0] address;
  rand bit         enable;

  // skipping constructor 

  task body;
      this.randomize();
      // do body stuff
  endtask
endclass

class sequenceB extends uvm_sequence;
  rand logic[31:0] address;
  rand bit         enable;

  // skipping constructor

  task body;
      // here I want this.address to match the address randomly generated in sequenceA
      // wait_till_sequenceA randomization is complete
      // this.address = sequenceA.address (??);
      // do body stuff
  endtask
endclass
```

Any clue on best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to synchronize traffic across multiple sequences, your best bet is using a virtual sequence:

```
class virtual_seq extend uvm_sequence;
  sequence_a seq_a;
  sequence_b seq_b;

  `uvm_declare_p_sequencer(virtual_sequencer)

  task body();
    // create sequence A
    // ...

    // start sequence A on appropriate sequencer
    fork
      seq_a.start(p_sequencer.seqr_a);
    join_none

    // wait until seq_a's item finishes
    // 'end_event' is built into uvm_transaction and is trigger
    // when the driver calls item_done()
    seq_a.seq_item_a.end_event.wait_trigger();

    // create sequence B based on seq_a.seq_item_a
    // ...

    // start sequence B
    fork
      seq_b.start(p_sequencer.seqr_b);
    join_none
  endtask
endclass
```

The `virtual_sequencer` class contains handles of both bus sequencers. We've implemented synchronization here by letting sequence A do an item and only then start sequence B. Notice that sequence A runs on while we do this, since we haven't killed it. You can implement any kind of synchronization here, like grabbing `seqr_a` to pause sequence A until a certain point in sequence B's execution, etc. To get more details have a look in the UVM user guide.

If you want to wait only until the `seq_a` created and randomized its `seq_item_a`, you'll have to define a hook event inside it:

```
class sequence_a extends uvm_sequence #(sequence_item_a);
  event item_randomized;

  task body();
    // create 'seq_item_a'
    // ...

    seq_item_a.randomize();
    -> item_randomized;
  endtask
endclass
```

In the virtual sequence code, instead of waiting on `end_event`, just wait on `item_randomized`.

You can also make the `item_randomized` event part of the sequence item itself and trigger it from `post_randomize()`:

```
class sequence_item_a extends uvm_sequence_item;
  event item_randomized;

  function post_randomize();
    -> item_randomized;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: The problem is that I need sequenceB to start as soon as sequenceA has created and randomized its sequence_item.
Right now I am leaning towards using a TLM analysis port/import to broadcast the sequenceA item to sequenceB, after both have been forked simulataneously.

Comment: Does it make sense to implement a analysis_port/import in the sequences to directly communicate from sequenceA to sequenceB? I would connect them up in the test connect_phase. I would call the write function in sequenceA in a post_randomize function.

Comment: @noobuntu No, You cannot have analysis ports in your sequences, I guess it's possible to have ports only in components.

Comment: @Vineeth VS - Yes, I realized this partway through my work.
I am now considering using a mailbox to communicate between the two processes. Unless there is an established way of doing what I want?

Comment: @noobuntu You're overthinking it. You can just create an event in `sequenceA` that is emitted once you've randomize the item. If you can't edit `sequenceA`, you can create the event in an extension of `seqItemA` and use a factory override.

Comment: @noobuntu You can have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to remove the randomize part from the sequence body (if possible) and randomizing it before the seq.start method shown in Tudor's answer.

```
class virtual_seq extend uvm_sequence;
  sequence_a seq_a;
  sequence_b seq_b;

  `uvm_declare_p_sequencer(virtual_sequencer)

  task body();
    // create sequences
    // ...

     // randomize seq A
     seq_a.randomize();
     //randomize seq  B 
     seq_b.randomize() with {address = seq_A.address;} 
     // start sequences
     // ...

  endtask
endclass
```